# using list of numbers formatted as strings to delete the rows in a dataframe containing those values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, string-formatting

I am trying to remove all of the rows from a dataframe if the row contains several possible strings that might be '2 yrs' or '3 yrs' or '4 yrs' and so on, all the way up as high as '30 yrs.'

To do this cleanly, I'd like to do this in one line. So I'm trying to write the code to refer to all of these numbers at once using string formatting.

If I wanted to remove just the row that contains '12 Yrs', this line works for that:
    df_x = df_x[df_x.Col.str.contains('%d Yrs' % 12) == False]

Where:

df_x is my dataframe

Col is my column name

So....

How can I remove all of the rows with all of the possible strings including '2 yrs', '3 yrs,' '4 yrs', and so on?

Here is my attempt:

```
year_numbers = range(0,30)
number_of_years = list(year_numbers)
df_x = df_x[df_x.Col.str.contains('%d Yrs' % tuple(number_of_years)) == False]
```

Output:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: one-line != *cleanly*

Comment: You can use lambda expression for that like this code: rows_with_strings  = df.apply(
       lambda row : 
          any([ isinstance(e, basestring) for e in row ])
       , axis=1)

Comment: @wwii The most helpful answer took care of it on one line!  But I get your point -- not always the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions with [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
df_x[~df_x.Col.str.contains(r'\d+ Yrs')]
```

The `\d+` will match any amount of numbers (but requires at least one), so it would also match `O Yrs`, `1000 Yrs` and so on.

Comment: if he only wants numbers up to 30 that might be a problem though, you'd have to really expand that expression I think

Comment: @MattTakao: the way the question was written, it sounds like the only inputs that exist go up to 30, not that OP wants to keep 31 and higher.  Anyway it's a trivial fix to update the regex if needed.

Comment: @JohnZwinck You are correct. There are no inputs greater than 30.

Comment: @ThomasErnste I'm glad it worked. Don't forget to also [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the most helpful answer to mark the issue as resolved. :)

Comment: I was just trying to figure out how to do that. Done!

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
import re

In [142]: df
Out[142]:
              Col
0   aaa 1 Yrs bbb
1   aaa 2 yrs bbb
2   aaa 3 Yrs bbb
3  aaa 10 yrs bbb
4  aaa 30 Yrs bbb
5  aaa 31 yrs bbb
6  aaa 50 Yrs bbb
7  xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

In [143]: df[~pd.to_numeric(df.Col.str.extract(r'(\d+)\s+yrs', flags=re.I, expand=False),
     ...:                   errors='coerce')
     ...:        .between(2, 30)]
     ...:
Out[143]:
              Col
0   aaa 1 Yrs bbb
5  aaa 31 yrs bbb
6  aaa 50 Yrs bbb
7  xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score -1):

How's this:

```
remove_years = ['{} Yrs'.format(x) for x in range(30)]
mask = df_x['Col'].apply(lambda x: x in remove_years)
df_x = df_x[mask]
```

You can combine the last two lines if you want

Comment: When you are using Pandas, `apply()` is almost never the right solution.  It's very slow.